# Making a more pythonic wrapper around a non-pythonic class

Tags: python, wrapper

I am going to use a library called `socket.io-python-emitter` (https://github.com/ziyasal/socket.io-python-emitter) in my project, however, the syntax it introduces really bothers me..

Example usage:

```
e = Emitter(...)
e.Emit('message')
e.In('group1').Emit('message')
e.In('group1').In('group2').Emit('message')
e.Of("/ns").In('group1').In('group2').Emit('message')
```

I guess the author have done it this way so the JavaScript/node.js people will feel more at home, but it it really makes it harder to code a dynamic emitter..

Ultimately, it should be (at least in my opinion):

```
e = Emitter(...)
e.emit('message')
e.emit('message', groups=['group1'])
e.emit('message', groups=['group1', 'group2'])
e.emit('message', groups=['group1', 'group2'], ns='/ns')
```

What is the best approach?

- Create a wrapper around this lib? Seams like that would be ugly...
- Fork the project and create a "pythonic" version? More ugly, and duplication.. Dont really want to do this.
- Submit a patch to add a pythonic way to the upstream project?

Comment: This is a rather [small script](https://github.com/ziyasal/socket.io-python-emitter/blob/master/emitter/__init__.py), and most of the code looks like a thin wrapper around `redis.publish`. I'd simply create my own class that wraps redis and works in the way I want.

Comment: Flat is better than nested.

Answer (score 0):

Your third option seems (to me, of course) the good approach. I would first talk to the author(s)/maintainer(s) to see how they feel about the idea.

Since you create a new method (and use keywords arguments anyway), both syntaxes can coexist, so I think there is no need to fork the project or create a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. I have submitted an issue @ https://github.com/ziyasal/socket.io-python-emitter/issues/8